# How to checkout the source code in Jenkins from Phabricator diffusion?

Tags: svn, jenkins, phabricator

I have done Phabricator setting and svn+ssh works well.
When I fill in the link to Jenkins, it shows **Unable to access to repository**.

[image]

After checking the Jenkins log, I get the following mesaage.

> May 15, 2017 4:35:40 PM SEVERE
>   hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$ModuleLocation$DescriptorImpl checkCredentialsId
>   svn: E200015: Authentication cancelled

I try to build the project and get the following message.

> Attempting a public key authentication with username dailybuild
>   Failed to authenticate: svn: E170001: Credentials rejected by SSH server.
>   FAILED: svn: E170001: Authentication failed for svn+ssh://vcsuser@192.168.1.185:2222/source/xxxx
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Authentication failed for svn+ssh://vcsuser@192.168.1.185:2222/source/xxxx
>       at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:53)
>   ...

I can checkout code by the ssh public key (.key) generated from Phabricator in  tortoise SVN, but it can't work in Jenkins

May Anyone help me to fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days trying, I found an easy way to checkout from Phabricator

1. create a vcsuser private key from server (not from Phabricator)
2. create a folder at /source
3. create a softlink in /source such as `sudo ln -s /var/repo/9 repo_name`
4. Add a credential to Jenkins from your private key

Now I can checkout source code from the link：

`svn+ssh://vcsuser@192.168.1.185/source/repo_name/branches/$branch_name`

Answer (score 0):

The main gotcha I've run into with SSH fetching in Jenkins (not specific to Phabricator) is that the host key needs to be in the jenkins user's known_hosts before the authentication over SSH will work.

It's a while since I encountered it, so I don't know if these messages are a sign of that issue, but I do recall it was a general authentication error, so difficult to track down the actual cause of the issue.